# Is there a way to prevent users from using Shared Drives instead of Shared Folders for project files?

Tags: google-drive

Our organization is using Google Drive as its main file repository. I'm facing a constant struggle as users share folders in their "My Drive" space and start using said folders as shared project spaces.

As admins among us will know, in Shared Folders like this, anyone adding/creating a file remains the owner, causing a horrible mess once people leave to organization, external partners add files, or you end up wanting to move the files to a Shared Drive (and many more issues...).

I can warn users about setting up Shared **Drives** for this, I can educate them on it, but I can't enforce it. Is there a way to disable Shared **Folders**, without disabling Shared **Drives**? Or are there any other ways to manage this?

(Start rant: I feel like Google Drive hasn't been designed for business use... it just feels shoehorned into it...)

Comment: Does the silence here mean this is not possible? @wouter, this is also a significant problem for my organization.

Comment: @user2943799: it's not possible. I've started internal training/awareness raising to work around it. 100 pushups for anyone that uses shared files/folders :)